# Tor Browser stops working notice when I try to install new 5.5.5 update

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, windows

My Tor browser was working fine until this last update (5.5.5), ran through the site to download new update, it installed to the point where I'm asked if I want to run the Tor Browser and install desktop and start icons.  Click yes, and boom, I get a box saying that the Tor Browser has quit working and it then gives me an option to check Microsoft online and close, or just close.  Checking Microsoft doesn't do anything and the box just closes and I'm no further along than before.  I tried turning off the WebRoot Security I have, no difference, and also got rid of my MalWareBytes software, thinking that might be causing a problem.  I saw a post about right clicking the file, going to properties, and then unchecking the box about it coming from another computer.  No difference.  Can anyone help?  Using a 32-bit Windows 7 OS with plenty of HD room.

Comment: Did you remove the old Tor Browser before you installed the new one? Installing it on top of an old one is likely to cause issues, you should let the native updater handle updates in those cases, or delete the old one first. If you did, delete the directory it was installed to and run through the install process again.